# Register a dependency Resolver class within wpf application using NInject

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a wpf application in which I'd like to use NInject as a Dependency injector

So I created the `Dependency Resolver` class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Parameters;
using Ninject.Syntax;

namespace NinjectWithWPF
{
   public class DependencyResolution 
    {
       public IKernel kernel;

       public DependencyResolution()
       {
           kernel = new StandardKernel();
           AddBindings();
       }

       private void AddBindings()
       {
           kernel.Bind<Icalcul>().To<CalculSimple>();
       }
       public object GetService(Type serviceType)
       {
           return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
       }

       public IEnumerable<Object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
       {
           return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
       }
    }
}
```

I need to know how can I register it at my dependency Resolver class in `App.xaml`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Parameters;
using Ninject.Syntax;

namespace NinjectWithWPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logique d'interaction pour App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

So I need to know

1. What is the proper way to do that?
2. In Which Configuration file can I register the dependency Resolver Class?